# Plotly: How to plot rectangle with gradient color in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Can a shape such as a rectangle have a smooth color gradient in Plotly?

I define the shape with a solid fill color as:

```
shapes=[dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='paper',
    x0=box_from, x1=box_to,
    y0=0, y1=1,
    fillcolor='Green',
    opacity=0.07,
    layer='below',
    line=dict(width=0),
)]
```

But I'd like the box not to have a solid color fill, but to have a smooth color gradient.

- This is the example in the documentation I'm following:
  https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes
- The docs on `fillcolor` aren't very extensive:
  https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-shapes-items-shape-fillcolor
- I guess `colorscales` don't apply to shapes:
  https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/

My guess is the answer is a simple "not supported", but perhaps someone else knows better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone will correct me if I'm wrong but I think that no, there is no straight implementation to fill with a gradient a shape. But to achieve a similar results you could plot several lines inside the rectangle specifying decreasing rgb values.

For example I added this for loop after the first rectangle definition in the documentation code (changing also the rectangle fillcolor to white).

```
for i in range(100):
    fig.add_shape(type='line',
    xref="x",
    yref="y",
    x0=2.5,
    x1=3.5,
    y0=i*(2/100),
    y1=i*(2/100),
    line=dict(
                color='rgb({}, {}, {})'.format((i/100*255),(i/100*255),(i/100*255)),
                width=3,
            ))
```

And the result is:

[image]

I know it's impractical and that it can increase a bit the running time but if you care only about the aesthetic it does the job.

Comment: Nice workaround, I like it. That's exactly the look I'm after. The tradeoff for (a little) performance is well noted. I'll leave the question open a tad longer to see if any other solutions come in, but that is a nice one.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at Edoardo Guerrieros excellent suggestion, you could also consider using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` where the last number sets the opacity of the color. This way you'lll make the background gradually appear behind your rectangle:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig=go.Figure()

for i in range(100):
    opac = 1-(i/100)
    fig.add_shape(type='line',
    xref="x",
    yref="y",
    x0=2.5,
    x1=3.5,
    y0=i*(2/100),
    y1=i*(2/100),
    line=dict(color='rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format((0),(0),(255),(opac)),
              width=5,))



fig.update_xaxes(range=[2, 4])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-1, 2.5])

fig.show()
```